# Probability of an "at least" Question

Tags: probability

> Five distinct standard six-sided dice are rolled. What is the probability that at least three of them show a $6$? (The dice are distinguishable)

It seemed to be an easy question, but we have an "at least" over here ... I don't even know how to form the cases (i.e. if we even have to)

Comment: The cases are:  you throw exactly $3$, exactly $4$, or exactly $5$.

Comment: Hint: Bernoulli's Trials might be helpful here

Comment: You could decompose "at least three show 6" into three disjoint events: "exactly three show 6", "exactly four show 6", and "exactly five show 6".

Comment: @WolverineA03 dont think your edit makes a difference

Comment: You´ve got the right hints. Now it´s your turn to use them!!! Please show now what you do with these hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bernoulli's Trials say That probablity of event happening r times out of n is given by $$P(X=r)=\binom{n}{r}p^{r}q^{n-r}$$
where p is the probablity of success (here showing 6 with $p=1/6$) and $q=1-p$.

So all you need to do is add $P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)$

Comment: Ah yes! I was missing the "$q^{n-r}$" part in my working, I didn't knew it was the Bernoulli's Trials, thank you for the clarification!